# nginx loading assets but not showing for wordpress app

Tags: css, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am using the following setup to run 2 applications on the same domain. If the first application returns 404 it tries the other one (wordpress on /blog).

```
location /blog {
    root /var/www/blog;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
location / {
    # ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 =200 /blog/$uri;
}
```

Every page loads as expected and assets return 200 and the correct content. 
But css and most images of those assets are not applied to the page, while a few work just fine.
The following is included:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

I understand that this is probably a bad configuration anyway but in my understanding it should still work.
Is there another configuration to achieve something similar?

EDITED:
The wordpress installation is located in */var/www/blog/blog/*

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly understand the problem but I suggest you bring out that php block outside and remove blog and $args after index.php uri.

Try this one instead, let me know if this works out. :)

```
location /blog {
    root /var/www/blog;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
location / {
    # ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 =200 /blog/$uri;
}
```

Comment: The php block outside somehow doesn't work. The $args are necessary for wordpress to work and the blog is needed since wordpress is in /var/www/blog/blog.